# Access global resources in an asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, webforms

```
meta:resourcekey="WizardStep1Resource1"
```

This is what I use to access a `App_LocalResources`.

How do I access a resource in `App_GlobalResources`?

SOLUTION: Create a resource called `Globalresource.resx` in `App_GlobalResources`. In the file set a property called Test with the text Hello. Then it is called like `Text='<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, Test%>'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Text='<%$ Resources:Resource, WizardStep1Resource1 %>'
```

Text is the name of the property you want to set. Resource is the name of the global Resourcefile resp. ResourceClass and WizardStep1Resource1 is the name of the Resource Text.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx

Comment: meta:resourcekey="<%$ App_GlobalResources:Resource.aspx.resx, LabelResource%>"??

Comment: Is resources=App_GlobalResources that is generated by default? also does Resource need .resx extension?

Comment: That's a special ASP.NET folder that you can add. Inside add an item of type global resource.

Answer (score 7):

You can only access a resource in App_GlobalResources explicitly, using the implicit wiring i.e. `meta:resourcekey="WizardStep1Resource1"` is applicable only for local resources

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

To access a resource in App_GlobalResources, use explicit localization like

```
   <%= (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourcesClass", "WizardStep1Resource1") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to access a Global resources from C# code and from javascript functions. Below you can see both ways.

Imagine that you created a Global resource named WholeSite, inside you have a row named UnexpectedError.

txTitle is TextBox field.

**C# Code**:

```
txtTitle.Text = Resources.WholeSite.UnexpectedError;
```

**Javascript/.aspx**:

```
alert("<%= Resources.WholeSite.UnexpectedError %>");
```