# Reference resource from .resx table c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, resources

I have just started to look at a Webforms application for the first time.
I want to add a button called "Edit Column Headings" to the project resources:

```
           <asp:HyperLink ID="EditButton" CssClass="button" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/Content/Headings/EditHeadings.aspx">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:MyProject, EditColumnHeadings %>" />
```

It has a resource table .resx that looks like this:
[image]

I added the resource using the **Add Resource** button, but it is crashing at runtime, and is not being included in the autogenerated .rc file that adds the `System.Resources` reference.

How can I reference the resource so it can be used at runtime?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405605/access-global-resources-in-an-asp-net-control?rq=1) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Aleksey I tried that but no joy

Comment: Are there any updates or solutions to this topic?